# How to implement a card-view block same as this example html/css/js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, latex

[image]

> *Just like this example build by `tcoloredbox` of `latex`.*

My problems are:

1. how to make the title, the `Loi image` part, be **adjusted by sentence length**?
2. how to make the position of the title, still the `Loi image` part, has a **changeable position**? Can pure css work this out?
3. if I want the **title sentence** be **changed** when I **click/hover** the title, how should I do that?

Ok, I have relaize that the math equations are indeed a problem, here is a new post about the problem:
[The new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67114931/how-to-render-markdown-language-in-html-blocks).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

https://codepen.io/seanstopnik/pen/f4482b76c1a6973f0f57b9f606c62e16

```css
/* For demo only */
body {
  padding: 60px;
}

/* Example */
.box {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.box:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.box__title {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.box__title--top-left {
  top: -52px;
  left: 10px;
}

.box__title--top-right {
  top: -52px;
  right: 10px;
}

.box__title--bottom-left {
  bottom: -52px;
  left: 10px;
}

.box__title--bottom-right {
  bottom: -52px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h6 class="box__title box__title--top-left">This is a title</h6>
  <p class="box__copy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis in veritatis excepturi animi, quisquam atque adipisci rerum vel architecto dolorem id molestiae obcaecati expedita reprehenderit ad aliquid tempore quae pariatur.</p>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <h6 class="box__title box__title--top-right">This is a title</h6>
  <p class="box__copy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis in veritatis excepturi animi, quisquam atque adipisci rerum vel architecto dolorem id molestiae obcaecati expedita reprehenderit ad aliquid tempore quae pariatur.</p>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <h6 class="box__title box__title--bottom-left">This is a title</h6>
  <p class="box__copy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis in veritatis excepturi animi, quisquam atque adipisci rerum vel architecto dolorem id molestiae obcaecati expedita reprehenderit ad aliquid tempore quae pariatur.</p>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <h6 class="box__title box__title--bottom-right">This is a title</h6>
  <p class="box__copy">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis in veritatis excepturi animi, quisquam atque adipisci rerum vel architecto dolorem id molestiae obcaecati expedita reprehenderit ad aliquid tempore quae pariatur.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Original statement >> *P.S. Mathjax is not a problem, if someone can make an example, I guess it would be more convenient if you drop the equations.*

Comment: Sorry, I thought the math equations won't be a problem. I am totally wrong.

Comment: the box did work. But when I add math equations there comes problem.

Comment: I am using the html code in markdown, but the math equations are not rendered under the html block. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I posted a new question, the link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67114931/how-to-render-markdown-language-in-html-blocks.