# How to render markdown language in html blocks?

Tags: html, markdown, render, mathjax, katex

**Background:** In markdown files, I want to generate some more complex elements, such as [this question I posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67099015/how-to-implement-a-card-view-block-same-as-this-example-html-css-js). So I am tried to do that by using original html/css.

**Problem:** But then I notice the markdown language won't be rendered in the html blocks.

My environment setting is:

- Editor: Atom
- Markdown Preview/Export: Markdown Preview Enhanced
- Math render: Katex

Then, I will show examples of markdown language not applied for html.

### Math

Input:

```
<h4>$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$</h4>

$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$
```

The result is:

[image]

You can see that the same equation in under the html block is not rendered.

### Reference

Input:

```
<div>
> ABCDEFC
> ABCDEFC
> > ABCDEFC
> ABCDEFC
</div>

> ABCDEFC
> ABCDEFC
> > ABCDEFC
> ABCDEFC
```

The result is:

[image]

Still, the `markdown` is not rendered.

### Question

So, how to render this math equation in html block in Markdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is actually very simple, this answer is written for anyone may have similar problem.

Normally `HTML blocks` end with a blank line. So the solution for this problem is to add a blank line between `HTML` and `Markdown`.

For instance, in the first example, instead of have

```
<h4>$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$</h4>
```

write

```
<h4>

$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$

</h4>
```

and everything will go right.

Similarly, instead of writing

```
<div>
> ABCDEFC
> ABCDEFC
> > ABCDEFC
> ABCDEFC
</div>
```

we should write

```
<div>

> ABCDEFC
> ABCDEFC
> > ABCDEFC
> ABCDEFC

</div>
```

I have been overthinking. Hope this solution can help people with similar problem.

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work for me, and may be dependent on your markdown engine. In Jekyll (kramdown), you need to write `<div markdown="1">...</div>`. See https://github.com/planetjekyll/quickrefs/blob/master/FAQ.md#q-jekyll-doesnt-render-markdown-when-adding-html-tags

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried MathML? That might work better for your use.

Comment: Yeah. I believe that Katex transform Tex language into MathML. But personally speaking, writing directly in MathML is kind of complicate.

Comment: Declare: **When @Goman60 post this answer**, I was only asking for math equations. I have added more examples.